# Converting data from .dat to parquet using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

Why the number of rows is different after converting from .dat to parquet data format using pyspark? Even when I repeat the conversion on the same file multiple times, I get a different result (slightly more or slightly less or equal to the original rows count)!

I am using my Macbook pro with 16 gb

.dat file size is 16.5 gb

spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.

I already have the rows count from my data provider (45 million rows).

First I read the .dat file

```
2011_df = spark.read.text(filepath)
```

Second, I convert it to parquet, a process that takes about two hours.
    `2011_df.write.option("compression","snappy").mode("overwrite").save("2011.parquet")`

Afterwards, I read the converted parquet file

```
de_parq = spark.read.parquet(filepath)
```

Finally, I use "count" to get rows numbers.

```
de_parq.count()
```

Comment: Since parquet is column based file, you might want to check the characters in the columns, there might be some special chars that are causing the split which in turn increases the rows. I would suggest looking/forcing the schema to get to know more about the error!

Comment: Thanks for your advise.
I used "substr" to define the columns since the files I have are in .dat format (fwf). My understanding i cannot use "schema" with such data format?
also, I faced this weird problem today, spark jobs are running very slowly all of a sudden!? Ex: I used your advise yesterday about converting dat file to parquet and it worked fine with 3 files. Today, I came back to use the same code on new dat files but it is very slow? I tried to run the code on the old files that already worked fine but the problem occurs again with these files??